# How to make the gdb tui window bigger

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, tui

I am debugging my application by using `gdb` in `tui` mode.

When I start my debugging session the main windows is split in 2 equal-sized parts.

- the window with the source code (upper side)
- the window where I can call gdb commands (lower side)

The 2 windows are the same exact size.

Is there any way or key combination to make the source code window bigger than the other ones? Anything to make it larger?

Comment: Did you consider using the `M-x gdb` mode of `emacs` ? Then such things are simpler (under *emacs*).

Comment: Hi Basile.I 'd prefer to sort it via any GDB command to be used from GDB console. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See [gdb manual for TUI commands](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Commands.html).

You basically need to issue something like: winheight SRC + 5 (to increase of some columns) or winheight SRC 20 (to set absolute value)

Comment: Hi Dbranko. it works. I first get the names of the windows by calling 'info win' and then I increase/decrease the size of number of columns I want (if that number is allowed by gdb..sometimes I get invalid height).

Comment: in newer `gdb` it might be `src` with non-capital letters -- `help winheight` should list the accepted window names

Comment: `winheight <tab>` will tab-complete names of currently-shown windows.